# Gitlab export: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle / directory

Tags: ubuntu, export, gitlab

I've installed GitLab from source (Ubuntu 16.04). So i tried following command to backup my gitlab system:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

Unfortunately, I only get the following error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle / directory
```

I just can't get it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the `gitlab-rails` folder (for instance `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/`)

Then try the same command from that folder.